# String replace function only for the content inside of a specified html tag

Tags: php, string, replace, tags

I need to use string replace function but only for the content inside of a specified html tag.

For expample I want to replace all strings `type=checkbox` to `type=radio` only inside of `div id=category` tag. Function `str_replace('type="checkbox" ', 'type="radio" ', $content)` does it for every string.

```
<div id="category">
 ...
 <input id="in-1" type="checkbox"  value="1">
 <input id="in-2" type="checkbox"  value="2">
 <input id="in-3" type="checkbox"  value="3">
 ...
</div>
 ...
<div id="topic">
 ...
 <input id="in-1" type="checkbox"  value="1">
 <input id="in-2" type="checkbox"  value="2">
 <input id="in-3" type="checkbox"  value="3">
 ...
</div>
```

Any ideas how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please note that id's must be unique within a document. You are using the same id's on each set of inputs, and that is invalid.

I recommend parsing and replacing the html with `DOMDocument`: **[Live demo (click).](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sLKKtd)**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHtml('
<div id="category">
 <input type="checkbox" value="1">
 <input type="checkbox" value="2">
 <input type="checkbox" value="3">
 <!-- I added this element for testing that only checkboxes are changed -->
 <input type="text" value="3">
</div>
<div id="topic">
 <input type="checkbox"  value="1">
 <input type="checkbox"  value="2">
 <input type="checkbox"  value="3">
</div>
');

$cat = $dom->getElementById('category');

$inputs = $cat->getElementsByTagName('input');

foreach ($inputs as $k => $input) {
  if ($input->getAttribute('type') === 'checkbox') {
    $input->setAttribute('type', 'radio');  
  }
}

$newHtml = $dom->saveHtml();

echo $newHtml;
```

Comment: thanks! but won't it be faster if I select a string inside of the entire html code (by certain unique strings for begining and end - e.g html tags, notes) and then make the string replacement function? It would be enough for me.

Comment: @Bajlo Parsing html with regex is a bad idea, messy, and prone to error. That's what DOMDocument is for. There's no reason you can't apply the same logic to be more broad, if that's what you're asking. Here, I did as you asked and selected the elements inside of category. You can select however you want. Don't forget to click accept if you appreciate my answer!

Comment: I can't use it because DOMDocument changes a position of script tags in my case. It ignored another html tags inside a script and put closing script tag right after the first one. Is it a way how to use it not to modify html code?

Comment: @Bajlo post this as a new question. I need to see a lot more detail about the issue and comments are not the appropriate place. If you leave a comment wit the link to your new question, I'll be glad to check it out and help if I can.